# React Native на андроид

Tags: javascript, android-studio, reactjs, android-sdk, react-native

Всем привет. Уже 3 дня пытаюсь запустить симулятор андроид для react native. Когда я скачал react native, папка android у меня не появилась. Решил я через android studio все запустить. Установил все по документации. Начинаю устанавливать android simulator. Нажимаю на create virtual device. Скачиваю Nougat и marshmallow. Думаю все теперб могу запустить, но кнопка next все равно запрещена. Что делать???

Answer (score 0):

попробуй genemotion - предпочитаю его, привычнее как-то и не надо связываться со студией (к железу она требовательна). В андроид студио в принципе все идет из коробки проверь обязательно, чтоб были установлены:
Android SDK Tools
Android SDK Platform-tools
Android SDK Build-tools